# Cancelled GET requests in Chrome when using jquery-reel.js

Tags: jquery, get, jquery-reel

I'm using the [jquery reel plugin](https://github.com/pisi/Reel) to created an image reel in my rails app. My implementation of the plugin looks like this:

```
        <%= image_tag "render_set_1/img00001.jpg", :class => "reel", :alt => "render_set_1/img00001.jpg", 
    :data => {:speed => "0.2", :frame => "2", :delay => "5", :frames => "119", :responsive 
=> "true", :draggable => "true", :timeout => "5", :path => "/assets/", :images => 
    "render_set_1/img#####.jpg|2..119"}, :id => "render-img" %>
```

It appears that some of the requests for the images are being cancelled, returning the error "Failed to load resource net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE", yet when I click the url to the image beside the error it takes me to the image, so the image is there on the server.

Then, if you open the network tab there is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeHBY.png). Also, this only seems to be happening on Chrome. On FF everything appears to work as expected.

Any ideas as to what may be causing this? Thanks in advance for any help.